# How to create Audit Log Trail in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, audit-trail

Following is Table Structure:

```
id | createdby | createddate | tablename | columnname | primaryid | oldavalue | newvalue | remarks
```

we get delimited file in which we have some values to update in 4 tables. Four tables have 10 Columns each. We do not know what to update. So we just update whole row against one Primary ID.

Now Challenges here are:

1. How to get Table Name, Column Name in Hibernate?
2. How to fetch Old Value; during an update? How to know which field we are updating has old value and we are now inserting new value? (We don't compared fields yet)

Comment: probably you can create a history table (copy of the existing tables) and maintain old record in that table and then compare the records with newly added data in your main tables. You can use spring AOP to automate the process. Can you be more clear in when you need to compare the values? and do you need SQL query to compare or spring solution.\

Comment: Check [Hibernate Envers - Easy Entity Auditing](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/)

Answer (score 3):

You can Implement EmptyInterceptor of Hibernate. In methods of EmptyInterceptor you are able to find the field name, previous value and current value.

Comment: Could you please also provide example for same?

Comment: You can refer this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/ or search on google there are many examples available on EmptyIntercetor

Comment: hi @fatherazrael, I think hibernate envers is also helpful for you. Here is example https://newcircle.com/s/post/115/easy_auditing_versioning_for_your_hibernate_entities_with_envers

Answer (score 2):

My favorite tool for this is [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/). You just annotate your entities as @Audited and envers takes care of the interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Spring AOP by writing a spring aspect before and after the execution of operation which will insert the data in audit tables

Comment: Could you please also provide example for same?